# r cmd batch log with date using crontab

Tags: r, cron

I am running 'R CMD BATCH' per day using crontab.
like this..

```
0 4 * * * R CMD BATCH my_script.R my_script.Rout
```

I want to add date(today) to Rout filename.

my_script_2020_10_28.Rout, my_script_2020_10_27.Rout

What should I do?

Comment: If you do not want to touch your Rscript, you can simply schedule another mv command 1 min after to rename my_script.Rout to your desired filename. Otherwise, I think the ideal way is to embed the IO operation in that Rscript. You may want to check the [`sink`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sink) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backticks to call the shell command `date` in your crontab entry:

```
0 4 * * * R CMD BATCH my_script.R my_script_`date +\%Y_\%m_\%d`.Rout
```